# how to change directory for folders serially

Tags: bash

I have several sub folders in a directory (dir.1 dir.2 dir.3 etc) containing files (p.dat and c.dat) from which I want to extract part of the content to a.dat. How can I adjust my directory path to read p.dat and c.dat in all the sub directories, serially?

I set dir=dir.* (where * indicate the series)

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in `ls | grep dir`

do
  cd $dir
  sed -n '1p' p.dat | awk '{printf("%15.3f",(($2-$1)/2+$1)*10-200)}' >> ../all.dat
  sed -n '2p' p.dat | awk '{printf("%15.3f",(($2-$1)/2+$1)*10-200)}' >> ../all.dat
  outkey c.dat >> ../a.dat
  cd ..
done
sort all.dat -o temp.dat
mv temp.dat a.dat
#more a.dat
```

Comment: `for dir in dir*`

Comment: ...and all the bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ finds, which explicitly includes both quoting your expansion -- `cd "$dir"` is necessary to correctly handle directory names with characters in IFS or which could be parsed as globs -- and checking the exit status of `cd` (`cd "$dir" || continue`). Much more efficient, btw, to put `>../all.dat` on the same line immediately after the `done`; then *everything* in the loop appends to that file, opening it just once rather than re-opening it over and over.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your comment. Do you suggest cd "$dir" || continue to replace cd $dir; and >../all.dat  immediately after done (same line)? when I tried this, this result shows 'cd: $dir: no such file or directory'.

Comment: That error message makes it look like you used the wrong kind of quotes. `cd "$dir" || continue` (the correct form) is not `cd '$dir' || continue`.

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks. I changed the line "for dir in 'ls | grep dir`" to "for dir in dir* `ls | grep dir`" but also not successful.

Comment: It's not clear from your last comment how you applied Cyrus's advice. It should just be `for dir in dir*; do`, with no `ls` or `grep` anywhere. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: ...that said, I'm not even sure that there's a good reason to be using `cd` at all. If you just make your loop work with `"$dir/p.dat"` and `"$dir/c.dat"`, then you don't need to use `cd` in either direction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the comments. I implemented all the suggestions and it works fine.

Comment: @Cyrus, many thanks.

Comment: Glad that helped! Since you solved your problem without getting the question into a state where it's collecting answers (as opposed to comments), feel free to just delete it. (Deleting an answered question is bad form, but that's not the case if it's just a comment thread).

Comment: ...that said, before you go -- looking at it, you're wanting to run that `awk` line on the first two lines of each file, right? It'd be a more efficient to skip the `sed` and have just one `awk` that exits after the first two lines; let me throw together a quick example...

Comment: ...so, consider `awk 'NR==3 { exit; } 1 {printf("%15.3f",(($2-$1)/2+$1)*10-200)}' <p.dat` to replace the two awk-involved pipelines with just one command that doesn't need sed.